# Run a macro over another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refer to another Workbook in my macro, so the function in the macro will also run over the other workbook

There is a button in one of the workbooks on one of the sheets that needs to cut and insert the whole row at the top of the list (row 2).it also needs to do this in one sheet of the a different workbook.

My main problem is with referring to the file. The main error I get are "Run-time error '9': subscript out of rang" or a "Object or method invalid"

The current code I have works until the comment.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim wbA As Workbook
Set wbA = Workbooks("MFDT Dashboard 3.0 PRE-alpha.xlsm")
'Loop through workbook

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    'Color cells
    If ws.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
    ws.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Else
    ws.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
    'Cut and insert
    If Not ActiveCell.Row = 2 Then
    ws.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Cut
    ws.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If

Next ws
'after this it stops working.

 wbA.Sheets("Enginlist").Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Cut
 wbA.Sheets("Enginlist").Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file to make changes in it.

replace

```
Set wbA = Workbooks("MFDT Dashboard 3.0 PRE-alpha.xlsm")
```

with

```
Set wbA = Workbooks.Open("PATH\MFDT Dashboard 3.0 PRE-alpha.xlsm") ' add path to file also
```

then at the end of the macro you need to close the file

```
wbA.close
```

But I always do it twice just to be sure, it has happened several times that a file is not closed.

```
on error resume next
wbA.close
wbA.close
on error goto 0
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be more appropriate to actually dismiss, or deal with, the prompts Excel throws when trying to close a workbook hat has been modified?

Comment: @Luuklag It's not the messages I'm dealing with. It's the fact that Excel says it closes the workbook but doesn't and the file is locked forever. It happened several times a day in the past, once I figuered out you could just close twice it has not happened again.

Comment: Good new!! the code functions properly. Bad news it still gives me the "Run time error "9" Subscript out of range". At:

Comment: ```wbA.Sheets("Enginlist").Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Cut```

Comment: Try `wbA.activate` and `wbA.Sheets("Enginlist").activate` before the line that causes the error

Comment: Exceptions for file operations should always be handled properly especially so in a workspace environment. Having to call close twice is a problem special to you which you have decided not to address properly but should not be necessary (or repeated) in other instances.

Comment: @Chrowno Enlighten us on how to handle that Excel says the file is closed but Windows refuses to allow others to use the file. It's not `application.displayalerts` I'm using. It's only if the file closes on the first attempt the second will create an error. If the first fails the second does closes it. Anyways. Tell us how to do it properly then.

Comment: @Andreas If you want help with a problem that is very specific to you, you should open your own question. As per rule of thumb, exceptions should be avoided, noticed, reported and handled in this order. I was simply pointing out the bad (and potentially dangerous) practise in your answer that has no use case for anyone else.